# best way to stop this wordpress duplicate content

Tags: seo

I noticed in google that actually searches in my blog are getting indexed on multiple pages resulting in duplicate content.  Suggestions on how to stop this?  example

/

```
?s=radiofixes
/page/10/?s=radiofixes
/page/11/?s=radiofixes
/page/2/?s=radiofixes
/page/3/?s=radiofixes
/page/4/?s=radiofixes
/page/5/?s=radiofixes
/page/6/?s=radiofixes
/page/7/?s=radiofixes
/page/8/?s=radiofixes
/page/9/?s=radiofixes
```

I was thinking paramaters in google, but would I put to ignore?

Answer (score 1):

Read this http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

There are several WordPress SEO plugins that can help, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=canonical&sort=

Comment: yeah i got all in one seo but it doesnt seem to be including searches at all

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here is not duplicate content. The problem is that your search result get indexed which is wrong for SEO reasons. Search engines like Google explicitly ask to avoid search result pages to get indexed.

To avoid your Wordpress search result pages to get indexed in search engines, you have different options :

## Easy way

[Block access to robots](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en) by adding the following instruction in your /robots.txt files :

```
Disallow: *?s=*
```

This will prevent from bots to access any resources with `?s=` in their URL.

## Good way

Add a `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow" />` in the `<head>` tag of your search result pages.

This will let bots access your search pages but will prevent from indexing.

### With Wordpress SEO by Yoast plugin

[Wordpress SEO by Yoast](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) is a well known plugin for optimizing Wordpress for SEO and considered as the best SEO plugin for now by many SEO professionals (as I am).

This plugin add automatically the right `<meta>` on search result pages.

### Without using a plugin

#### With header included

If you use the same header for different templates with `get_header()` function for instance, you will need to test if  the current page is a search result page before adding the `<meta>` tag.

Here is the code to add in your header template (default: `header.php`) :

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : ?>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

#### Without header included

If you use a simple template with his own header, you can simply edit you search template `search.php` to add the `<meta>`tag in the `<head>`